# Losing Audio When Converting VOB to MPEG-2 using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-2, vob

I'm using FFMPEG to convert VOB files to MPEG2 using `ffmpeg -i file.vob -c copy
out.mpg`.

It's converting the video fine, but the audio doesn't play on the resulting
files. I get the

```
[mpeg @ 0x118afc0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5005000
```

error, but setting `-analyzeduration` to 9999999 or higher doesn't get
rid of the error.

I think it's reading the stream correctly:

```
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavf53.32.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video, yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31,
                      6124 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
  Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 256 kb/s`
```

Here's info on my install

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.6 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Dec 11 2012 23:58:43 with gcc 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg
--incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man
--arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic'
--enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass
--enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
--enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2
--enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter
--enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared
--enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64
--enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, 256 kb/s
```

You are trying to mux an AC3 stream into an MPEG container. You
[cannot do this](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats).
You could use a different container

```
ffmpeg -i file.vob -c copy out.mkv
```

or perhaps allow FFmpeg to transcode the audio

```
ffmpeg -i file.vob -c:v copy out.mpg
```